# Custom c# GP Tool ArcGIS Server 10.1 - build for 'Any CPU', x86, or 64bit? Does it matter?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, .net

I think I understand most explanations of these targets, but I get confused in the context of ArcGIS customizations like this because what we are compiling has to work in conjunction with ArcGIS, not just by itself.

We are having trouble getting our tool to register on ArcGIS Server 10.1 with esriregasm, though it works on Desktop. Build platform is one variable, so I thought I'd ask which I should build for when the intent is for the tool to be installed on ArcGIS Server 10.1.

Comment: it does not matter. I was able use for both 32 bit and 64 bit platform

Answer (score 5):

I would say that you should use Any CPU for all your assemblies.  Any exes will need to be compiled for x86 if they are using ArcObjects.

Here is a helpful article from Stack Overflow-

> “An AnyCPU assembly will JIT to 64 bit code when loaded into 64 bit
>   process and 32 bit when loaded into a 32 bit process.”
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean

Here is some good info from ESRI --

> ArcGIS Desktop and Engine are 32 bit applications
>   - Run as 32 bit applications on a 64 Bit OS
>
> Standalone applications
>   - Set platform to x86 in Visual Studio Configuration  Manager 
>   - Default is “Any CPU”
>
> http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/arcgis_10_desktop_developer_migration_topics.pdf